# Mounted drive changed mount point after motherboard change in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, mount, ubuntu-14.04

I changed chassis and switched motherboards from an Asus Z87I-Pro to an Asus Z87-Pro - essentially the same except for form factors. While switching, I made note of how the hard drives were connected, and connected them to the same slots on the new motherboard.

Now, when I start the computer, everything works as intended, save that when the secondary drive is mounted, it's mounted at `/media/myname/drivename1` - whereas it used to be `/media/myname/drivename` without the extra 1.

If I try to e.g. `ls -l /media/myname/drivename`, I get "Permission denied", or "total 0" if I sudo it. Of course, I could just get used to using drivename1 instead, but I'd rather resolve the issue by changing the mount point name back if possible, especially since I would rather not need to rehash over 2 TB of data for some applications.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that for some reasons the folder `/media/myname/drivename` had been existed for some reasons at the moment when you once turned your machine so the system created new one. As you can see it holds root privileges but it's not using any longer and the size is 0. So I think you can just remove it with root privileges:

`sudo rm -r /media/myname/drivename`

here you freed the name,

after next reboot your hard drive should be mounted as usually to the `/media/myname/drivename` not `/media/myname/drivename1`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't dare try testing that before, but it worked brilliantly.